# How do I reconnect HTTP to HTTPS with subdomain?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

**I have the following HTTP address:**

```
http://www.example.com/
```

**but my HTTPS address has a subdomain and no www, like this:**

```
https://secure.example.com/
```

---

**I tried the following rule:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secure.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

**Which sent me to:**

```
https://secure.www.example.com/
```

---

How can I force HTTPS in this situation? As I need the www removed.

---

**EDIT:** I have these rules above them for 'fancy urls' as I'm using WordPress as CMS:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be your complete htaccess :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
#1--Redirect "http://domain to "https://secure"
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secure.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#2--wp rules--#
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately people don't know the subdomain as it's only used with the HTTPS.

Comment: Do you want to redirect the main site to subdomain?

Comment: Yes. I want to redirect the main site `http://www.` to `https://secure.` while keeping the WordPress rules working for fancy urls (look EDIT made in OP). Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secure.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

OR

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://secure.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Both rules do exactly this: any non-https request is redirected to https://secure.example.com while preserving the whole url

Comment: It works for the homepage, but not for the other links. Probably has to do with rules I have already set above them.

Comment: remove all rules, just leave mine. Try first one, if you don't like it try second one, but don't try them together, they are doing the same thing.

Comment: Unfortunately that breaks WordPress 'fancy urls'.

Comment: you never mentioned you have wordpress )) and other rules. But this is the logic you should follow.. it will catch any non-http requests, and converts them to https. Whats next is up to the script you have, or Wordpress in your case,

Comment: I'm sorry, I never noticed until later. I edited my post.

Comment: you need to look at wordpress documentation. it's not an isolated .htaccess question. Quick google search gave me this : https://wordpress.org/support/topic/https-on-subdomain-issues-when-viewing-regular-domain